# Convergence of the probability of RV with negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am seeking an answer to this question.

> Given the number of tools successfully produced $R$ before the $yth$ failure follows a negative binomial distribution $(y,p)$.
>
> $$
> P(R=r)=\begin{pmatrix}r+y-1\\
> r
> \end{pmatrix}(1-p)^{y}p^{r}
> $$
>
> Prove that $P(R=r)$ converges to $0$ as $y$ increases.

I can see that I need to prove that the factorial ratio 
$
\begin{pmatrix}r+y-1\\
r\end{pmatrix}
$ is going to infinity slower than $(1-p)^y$ is going to $0$, as $y$ increases.

Comment: Can you rephrase you last thought?  What more precisely would be the way to compare the rate of one expression "going to infinity" with another expression "going to 0"?

Comment: @hardmath I notice the below answer uses ratio test, you mean there is another way ?

Comment: That approach doesn't directly compare how fast the "factorial ratio" goes to infinity with how fast $(1-p)^y$ goes to zero, as you approached the problem.  Rather it shows that $f(y+1)/f(y)$ is approximately $(1-p)$ for sufficiently large $y$ (in comparison to $r$), and this is a positive ratio bounded below $1$ (for positive $p \in (0,1)$).  I wanted to draw you out on how to make your approach to the problem more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(y)=\binom{r+y-1}{r}(1-p)^yp^r$, where for this answer $r$ is fixed.

Look at $\frac{f(y+1)}{f(y)}$. This is equal to 
$$\frac{(r+y)!}{y!r!}\cdot \frac{(y-1)!r!}{(r+y-1)!}(1-p),$$
which simplifies to 
$$\frac{r+y}{y}(1-p).$$
For fixed $r$, the fraction  $\frac{r+y}{y}$ has limit $1$ as $y\to\infty$. If $p\ne 0$, then by the Ratio Test the series 
$$\sum_1^\infty f(y)$$
converges, and therefore $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)=0$.